# checking that a number is within range

Tags: c#

am trying to make a mastermind game using an array of ints where I having the user guess a number sequence between 4-10 instead of colours. My GetAValidNumber is suppose to displays a prompt to the user and
get a number from the user in the minimum/maximum range as specified in
the parameters. If the number entered is outside the minimum/maximum
range, then an error message is suppose to be displayed and
the user is re-prompted for the number but for some reason it isn't validating properly.

Any Guidance would be appreciated

```
    public static int GetAValidNumber(string inputMessage)
    {
        // declare variables
        int validInteger;
        bool inputIsValid = false;
        int lowValue = 1;
        int highValue = 10;
        while (!int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out validInteger))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Invalid entery - try again.");
            Console.Write(inputMessage, lowValue, highValue);
            do
            {
                while (!int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out validInteger))
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Invalid entery - try again.");
                    Console.Write(inputMessage);
                }
                if (validInteger < lowValue || validInteger > highValue)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Your number is out of Range: ");
                }
                else
                {
                    inputIsValid = true;
                }

            } while (validInteger < lowValue || validInteger > highValue);
        }
        return validInteger;
    }

    // This method directs the play of the game
    public static void PlayGame()
    {
        int userNumbers;
        int userGuess;
        int difficulty;
        int randomNumbers;

        Console.WriteLine("How Many Numbers Would You Like To Use When Playing(4-10): ");
        userNumbers = GetAValidNumber(Console.ReadLine());

        Console.WriteLine("Choose a difficulty level (1 -3");
        difficulty = GetAValidNumber(Console.ReadLine());
        Console.WriteLine("A 5-digit number has been chosen. Each possible digit may be the number 1, 2, 3, or 4");
        Console.ReadLine();
        Console.WriteLine("Enter Your Guess {0} guesses remaning", GetGameDifficulty(difficulty, randomNumbers = GetRandomNumberCount(difficulty)));
        userGuess = GetAValidNumber(Console.ReadLine());
        Console.WriteLine("Your Guess was {0}, Your Results are {1}", userGuess, CountHits(userGuess, randomNumbers));
        Console.ReadLine();

    }
```

Comment: Does this even compile? You should take care about formatting your code in questions so that it is easier to read.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a simplified version of your code:

```
    public static int GetAValidNumber(string inputMessage)
    {
        int validInteger = 0;

        //Range between 4 to 10
        int lowValue = 4; 
        int highValue = 10;

        int.TryParse(inputMessage, out validInteger);

        while (validInteger < lowValue || validInteger > highValue)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Invalid entery - try again.");
            inputMessage = Console.ReadLine();
            int.TryParse(inputMessage, out validInteger);
        }
        return validInteger;

    }
```

The issue here is you are having multiple `while` loops that is not validating your inputs correctly.

Take note that on your other validating number inputs you need different ranges so I would suggest setting the `lowValue` and `highValue` as extra parameters on your function:

```
public static int GetAValidNumber(string inputMessage, int lowValue, int highValue)
```